# How to install xfce4-xfapplet-plugin on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, xfce, xfce-panel, gnome2

I would like to add GNOME2 applets to an XFCE panel. According to [this](http://bapoumba.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/add-gnome-applets-to-the-xfce-panel/), I should install `xfce4-xfapplet-plugin`. I can't do `sudo apt-get install xfce4-xfapplet-plugin` because [`xfce4-xfapplet-plugin` is only available for Lucid.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/xfce4-xfapplet-plugin)

Does anyone know how I can get use GNOME2 applets in XFCE? Thanks.